# How to transfer name/value pairs to XML?

Tags: c#, xslt

I would like to transform my name/value-pairs to XML via XSLT Transformation.
This should work with the XslCompiledTranform. All this seems pretty clear. But what is the best way to use the name/value pairs? Using an XML to transform to HTML and things like that are pretty clear. I am just confused about the unstructured name/value pairs.

Comment: In what form are your name/value pairs to begin with?

Comment: The name/value pairs are in an c# field collection. I need to read the name/value out of the collection and would like to transfer it to an xml-structure. Therefore I am searching a possibility to transform the fields of the collection to xml via XSLT Transformation to be able to control it from outside the code.

Comment: To use an XSLT transformation, you'll really need your collection in XML format in the first place, so you are better off just writing some C# code to read all the elements in the collection, and building up an XML document manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Tim C* says in the comments for the question, XSLT is used to transform **XML documents** into other documents, usually *other* XML documents. It can't be used to transform .NET collections, unless you first serialize them into an XML document, in which case you don't need XSLT to turn a collection into XML.